# ArrayFile GFor not working

Tags: arrayfire

I'm try to run a gfor loop but this only run once...

Someone can help me?

```
gfor(seq j, gammaStep-1){
    vector<predicao> vals;
    countLoop = (int) sqc(j).scalar<float>();
    double localGamma = (countLoop+1)*incGamma;
    vector<rbf> rbfs = mountRbf(X1, Y1, localGamma);
    for (int i = 0; i < XT.size(); i++){
        double p = prediction(XT[i], rbfs, localGamma);
        predicao p1;
        p1.val = p;
        p1.err = abs(XT[i] - p);
        vals.push_back(p1);
    }
    double sumErr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++){
        sumErr += vals[i].err;
    }
    double media = sumErr / vals.size();
    double vary = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++){
        vary += pow(vals[i].err - media, 2);
    }
    double dev = sqrt(vary);
    eM[countLoop] = media;
    eD[countLoop] = dev;
}
```

In the end of processation, only the first position of eM and eD was calculated...

Comment: An update, i've calculted all gammas before enter the gfor... but still calculating the same thing for all instancies.
In a minimal example, works well... (calculate a 2-pow)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points might help here :

1. Don't convert the **j** index to a scalar.
2. Remove in-place accumulators like

   sumErr += vals[i].err;
3. Use only af::array types as much as possible within the **gfor** loop

But the primary concern is the call to

```
 prediction(XT[i], rbfs, localGamma)
```

That would need to be fully vectorized so it can run in a parallel loop.
**gfor** can't automagically parallellize an arbitrary function.

If, on the other hand, you just want to parrallelize the other logic - the calculation of RMS error, you can pull the call to prediction out of the loop, load the results into af::arrays, parallelize the code to calculate each error, finally taking the sum **outside** of the parallel loop.